# An exception occurred during merging: using ILMerge

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, ilmerge

I am trying merging DLL files using the ILMerge tool.

The command line I used is

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\ILMerge>ilmerge /t:dll /out:NewFile.dll D:\victor\Excelimport.dll D:\victor\BOL3.dll**
```

But I got the following error. Can anyone tell me why I got this error: *Unresolved assembly reference not allowed*

```
An exception occurred during merging:
Unresolved assembly reference not allowed: Microsoft.Dexterity.Shell.

   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.GetAssemblyRefIndex(AssemblyNode assembly)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.GetTypeRefIndex(TypeNode type)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.VisitReferencedType(TypeNode type)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.VisitClass(Class Class)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.VisitModule(Module module)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.SetupMetadataWriter(String debugSymbolsLocation)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.WritePE(Module module, String debugSymbolsLocation, BinaryWriter writer)
   at System.Compiler.Writer.WritePE(String location, Boolean writeDebugSymbols, Module module, Boolean delaySign, String keyFileName, String keyName)
   at System.Compiler.Writer.WritePE(CompilerParameters compilerParameters, Module module)
   at ILMerging.ILMerge.Merge()
   at ILMerging.ILMerge.Main(String[] args)
```

Comment: after ran that commnad i got dll file. NewFile.dll file.But size is 0 KB.

Comment: Thanks joey for modification of my question.

Comment: Is Microsoft Dynamics GP installed on the machine you run this on?  Required.

Comment: yes, GP installed on my machine.

Comment: Use Fuslogvw.exe to troubleshoot assembly resolution problems.